# How to draw a circle only WITHIN a certain area?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

So I have a circle that is being drawn on a canvas, it changes size according to a setting. However, if the setting is set too high, the circle is bigger than it's reserved area, and overlaps other things in the canvas.

I'm currently erasing the area surrounding the box after it is drawn, but it causes difficulties. I basically have to draw everything around it twice because I need the circle to be drawn last. This makes it more difficult to implement click actions in said surrounding area, because the click is registered twice.

TL;RD: How could I mask out part of a circle *before* I draw it on the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use the clip() function.

```
       context.rect(50,50,200,200);//the area in which the circle is to be drawn
       context.save();//saved context so it can be restored later
       context.clip();
       //now draw your circle
       context.restore(); //remove the clip
```

Only the area inside the given rectangle is drawn.

Here is a [good tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-clipping-region-tutorial/) on the subject.

Comment: That works, although I can't seem to clear it. Now only the circle box is drawn. restore() doesn't do anything.

Comment: Maybe you can post a simple jsfiddle with you code that way we can suggest why it may not be working.

Comment: I can try, but it might take a moment to extract that part out of the whole.

Comment: make sure that you save() before clipping.

Comment: Ah dammit, I can't believe I missed that lol. It works now, infinite thanks to you. This makes my code a ton easier.